# How to rename particular files in the folder for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9

I have a folder, consider its location is `/home/itsme/videos`. Folder contains many files (files with extension .txt, .rb, .mp4 etc).

But from that files I have to rename only **.mp4**  files. I'd like to rename the files on the spot, without moving them. How can I achieve this using **ruby**.

For this I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: you need refine code for you needs i down vote you because my answers work.

Comment: All these are working code and you must configure it with your needs as Monk_Code suggests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is going to be trick, here I am using `FileUtils.mv` method.

```
path = "/home/itsme/videos"
Dir.open(path).each do |p|
  next if File.extname(p) != ".mp4"
  filename = File.basename(p, File.extname(p))
  newname = filename.upcase + File.extname(p)  
  FileUtils.mv("#{path}/#{p}", "#{path}/#{newname}")
end
```

To use **FileUtils class** method you have to include it by using `require fileutils`

Comment: let me know feedback on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
path = "/home/itsme/videos"
Dir.open(path).each do |p|
 next if p.match(/^\./)
 old = path + "\\" + p
 new = path + "\\" + p.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')
 File.rename(old, new)
 puts old + " => " + new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "/home/itsme/videos"
  Dir.open(path).each do |p|
  next if File.extname(p) != ".mp4"
  // Renaming happens here
  new = path + "\\" + p.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')
  File.rename(p, new)
end
```

Same as Kingston's Answer but very specific to the requiements.
This will skip anything that is not MP4 and rename the mp4 file with the new name.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tired your solution but it is giving me `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`. though there are so many .mp4 files are present.

Comment: Have you specified the right directory path ?? I have tested this solution and it works for me, try specifying the absolute path and not relative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if [File#rename](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-rename) return 0 that mean file renamed and raises a `SystemCallError` if the file cannot be renamed. `Dir["./home/itsme/videos/*.mp4"]` return array of files this `mp4` extension:

```
Dir["./home/itsme/videos/*.mp4"].each do |file|
  begin
  if File.rename(file, "new_filename").zero?
    puts "Change name #{file}"
  end
  rescue SystemCallError
    puts "Can't rename #{file}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try:

```
Dir.chdir("/home/itsme/videos") do
    unless Dir.glob("*.{mp4}").empty?
        Dir.glob("*.mp4", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).each_with_index do |file, index|
            File.rename(Dir.glob("*.mp4", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)[index],"some_other_name_#{index}.mp4")            
        end
    end
end
```

Ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-rename, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html

Hope this works :)